# script to get source code of website (js)

Tags: javascript

My school blocked CTRL + U, but you can use 'view-source:' before a link to view the code. It takes awhile, so i've been trying to make a script to automatically direct to the source code. However, I keep getting errors because it is not a link

I have tried the following:

```
var code = fetch(`view-source:https://${location.hostname}${location.pathname}`);
location.href = (code);
```

and

```
var code = (`view-source:https://${location.hostname}${location.pathname}`);
location.href = (code);
```

In the first one, I see a bad request, and in the second, I a blank page with the words "view-source:" followed by the link

Comment: `fetch()` doesn't return a URL you can assign to `location.href`. It returns a promise, which you can use to get the contents of the web page.

Answer (score 1):

`view-source:` isn't a real protocol you can `fetch()`.

However, just

```
var resp = await fetch('http://...');
var text = await resp.text();
document.body.textContent = text;
```

should replace the current document's body with the text contents of that URL...

Answer (score 1):

If you try from frontend to fetch the source code you will run to CORS Problems. But you can use some proxyies like in the example beloow:

```js
fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75440023/script-to-get-source-code-of-website-js#75440023').then((response) => response.text()).then((text) => console.log(text));
```